# How to find total reputation gained/lost from a post

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

How can I see *all* of the actions that have affected my reputation from a single post, along with the total reputation change?

Comment: Given that some posts have been voted on over a long period of time, added to complications involving the rep cap, actually calculating how a given post has affected one's reputation isn't always very easy to calculate.  You could figure it out from the rep dump, but not particularly easily.

Comment: Sha, if I misunderstood your question, let me know, but what I edited it is my best interpretation of what you were asking.

Comment: @Servy, Actually it can give me what I want, But I was thinking about a simple filter for question in reputation tab

Comment: Is the vote count on posts not sufficient as a guide as to the reputation changes you have had?

Comment: @Tanner It's also useful, but when bounties counted it becomes too far.

Comment: @Tanner If the author is often hitting the rep cap, no, it's not actually a very good indicator.

Comment: @Servy yeah that's true in general, however, I did check the users profile and saw no instance of rep cap being hit or the mortarboard badge, so discounted that as a factor.

Comment: @Tanner That this one user wouldn't need it (unless he's looking at someone else's post, which is actually reasonable) doesn't mean it wouldn't be a useful feature to have.

Answer (score 26):

You can download your reputation audit log at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, then grep for the post ID.

For example, for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29193831), I got capped upvotes, uncapped upvotes, an accept vote and a bonus. The ID is 29193831 (see the *share* link), and in my reputation log I have the following entries for that post:

```
 2  29193831 [0]
 2  29193831 [0]
 2  29193831 [0]
 2  29193831 (10)
 1  29193831 (15)
 9  29193831 (150)
```

The first column is the vote type; 2 is an upvote, 1 is accept, and 9 is a bounty award. Square brackets are reputation-cap scores (so capped), between parenthesis I got the full score for the event.

Sum those values; for that post I got 10 + 15 + 150 == 175 points.

Comment: +1 Actually, I can download this and use it in a program like an Excel VBA code to make them like a sheet and so on ... ;).

Comment: @sha.T However, every +0 (rep cap upvote) is just the votes "late in the day", and if an earlier vote went away one of them would magically become a +10.  A "fairer" way to determine this is to add up how much rep you "would have gotten" without the rep cap on rep capped actions (up and downvotes), divide that by 200 (the cap) to get K, then use 10/K for the value of each upvote that day.